# File attachment works in Microsoft Bot Emulator but not in Skype

Tags: c#, botframework, skype-bots

I want to send an attachment (.txt) to Skype client using Microsoft Bot Framework V3 with Bot Builder Nuget package (3.2.0)

This is how I created the attachment:

```
var replayFile = new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Attachment();
replayFile.Name = "FileName";
replayFile.Content = "ByteArray";
replayFile.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

This works for the Bot Emulator (3.0.0.59), but my skype client(7.26.0.101) on Windows 10 sees only the message's text, but not the attachment.

I also tried Skype's Web UI in outlook.com, also no attachment.

In this document: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html

It says:

> If it is a file then it will simply come through as a link

Does this mean the only way to send a file using the BotFramework is via a link? Sending directly is not possible? But how come it works using the Emulator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send an image rather than a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246174/send-an-image-rather-than-a-link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why does it work in the Emulator, but sending a byte array through the Content property is not supported.
However, according to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/809#issuecomment-235125516) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/861#issuecomment-236275874) comments, you can send an attachment using a base64 encoded data URI:

```
byte[] data = GetAttachmentData();
var contentType = "text/plain";
var replayFile = new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Attachment
{
    Name = "FileName.txt",
    ContentUrl = $"data:{contentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(data)}",
    ContentType = contentType
};
```

Comment: On a side note, you do not have to specify which kind of image you upload.
"data:image;base64,..." works like a charm.

Comment: @srichakradhar If the same approach doesn't work, I think you have to ask a separate question on Stack Overflow